# Find all the equilibrium points of this second-order equation $x''+2x'=3x-x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find all the equilibrium points of this second-order equation $x''+2x'=3x-x^3$
I know that you must the roots of the equation, but when the equation isn't equal to $0$ I am confused on where to begin, thank you for any help!

edit: sorry, i did leave out a prime in there.  It is fixed now

Comment: Is the problem written correctly? One approach is to write the second order system as a system of first order equations.

Comment: Are you missing a derivative? It is strange to have $x$ terms on both sides of the equation. $x''+2x'=3x-x^3$ would make more sense.

Comment: @Sun: You can write it as a system of two first order equations and then find the $3$ critical points $$(x, y) = (0,0), (\pm~ \sqrt{3}, 0)$$ You can also draw a phase portrait of that system.

Comment: @Moo How could i rewrite it as a system of 2 1st order equations? thank you for your help

Comment: @Sun: http://www.math.poly.edu/courses/ma2132/Notes/MA2132EquationsToSystems.pdf

Comment: @Moo Thank you very much! That was a wonderful link!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, I agree with the usual method used by Moo and Lutz. Let me propose an alternative approach.

$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+2\frac{dx}{dt}=3x-x^3\quad$is an autonomous ODE. It is well known that the reduction of order is obtained thanks to the change of function :

$\frac{dx}{dt}=u(x(t))\quad\to\quad \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=\frac{du}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)u \quad\to\quad \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+2\frac{dx}{dt}= \left(\frac{du}{dx}\right)u+2u=3x-x^3$
$$\left(2+\frac{du}{dx}\right)u=3x-x^3$$
The stationary points are obtained for $\quad\frac{dx}{dt}=0 \quad\to\quad u=0 \quad\to\quad 0=3x-x^3$
$$x(3-x^2)=0 \quad\to\quad \begin{cases}x=0\\ x=\pm\sqrt{3}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

The equilibrium points are such that $x'=x''=0$. Hence $x=0,\pm\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 0):

You set $y=x'+2x$, then
$$
x'=y-2x\\
y'=3x-x^3
$$
and setting $x'=0=y'$ gives the stationary points.

Comment: Thank you very much! How did you find y' though? I see how you got y and x'

Comment: $y'=x''+2x'$ and then use the given ODE.